# Cómo puedo hacer todas las combinaciones posibles de numeros binarios de 16 bits? En java

Tags: java, coma-flotante

Tengo una función que me retorna el número decimal de un númetro binario de 16 bits, y necesito una funcion que me retorne todos los valores decimales de todos los números binarios de 16 bits posibles (65.3535) y no logro descifrar cómo. agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Empieza con el 00000.......00000 y vete sumando un 1 binario hasta que el numero sea igual a 11111.......11111. Para cada numero que salga llamas a tu funcion.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Sabes cómo puedo sumar ese 1binario? que no sea sólo un 1 entero y haga las iteraciones incompletas

Comment: Sumar 1 es igual en todas las bases: `for (int i=0;i != 0b1111_1111_1111_1111;i++) {...}`